# How to set button value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web-deployment

I want to set different values of button under different situations. The modal display style is "none" at first. I try to use `$("#submitform").value ="Add Event";` however, it doesn't work. When the modal pops up, the button value is still empty.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    btn.onclick = function() {
        $("#submitform").value ="Add Event";
        modal.style.display = "block";
    };
```

```html
<div id = "myModal" class = "modal">
<form name="addEvtForm" class="addEvtForm" >
  title:<input type="text" name="title" id="title" autocomplete="title"><br>
  <input type="button" value="" id="submitform">
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are you  getting myBtn from??

Comment: don't scramble jQuery with JS like this ..

Comment: That was my problem when trying to debug this script

Comment: just ignore "myBtn", that is used to trigger modal pop up. sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you didn't add jQuery to the html, so the .value didn't work.
Second, there was invalid syntax for your code.
I fixed it up:

```js
$("#submitform").click(function() {
        $('#submitform').val('Add Event');
        $(".modal").css("display", "block");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "myModal" class = "modal">
<form name="addEvtForm" class="addEvtForm" >
  title:<input type="text" name="title" id="title" autocomplete="title"><br>
  <input type="button" value="" id="submitform">
</form>
</div>
```

This should work.

Comment: I guess it would be better to remove the only jQuery instruction and keep JS instead of turning everything to jQuery

Comment: I just use jQuery cause it's easier to use, and I am better at it. If they specifically ask for javascript and no jQuery, then I would do that. Also, jQuery is a tag on the question.

Comment: yes my mistake. jQuery is what I want. I think jQuery is a library of js.

Answer (score 2):

try :

```
$('#submitform').val('Add Event');
```

or:

```
document.getElementById("submitform").value = "Add Event";
```